# Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be a set. We consider the relations on $X$ as subsets of $X\times X$. Let $U\subseteq X\times X$ be a subset, and let $S_U$ be the set of all equivalence relations on $X$ that contain $U$ as subset.

Show that $$R:=\bigcap_{S\in S_U}S$$is an equivalence relation on $X$.

$$$$

For that we have to show that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

We have that $S_U$ is the set of all equivalence relations on $X$, therefore an element $S\in S_U$ is an equivalence relation, isn't it?

An element of $R$ is of the form $S_1\cap S_2\cap \ldots \cap S_n$, where $S_i\in S_U$ are equivalence relations.

So we have to show that the intersections of equivalence relations are still equivalence relations, or not?

Comment: An element of $R$ is an element of $X \times X$, so it seems strange to think of it as an intersection of sets...

Comment: Suppose that $X=\mathbb{Z}$ and $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\mid x+y\geq 100\}$, how can we define $R$ in that case? @TheoreticalEconomist

Comment: Isn't $R$ defined exactly as in your question? I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.

Comment: What is $R$ when $X=\mathbb{Z}$ and $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\mid x+y\geq 100\}$ ? @TheoreticalEconomist

Comment: It seems like reflexivity will require $R=\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, but I want to think about that a bit more carefully. Btw, this question is distinct from your original post, so you should probably post a new question, especially since your original question has already been answered below.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're having a bit trouble with the notation. You are correct in thinking that an element $S \in S_U$ is an equivalence relation. Each $S \in S_U$ is an equivalence relation and therefore some subset of $X \times X$. So $R$, which is the intersection of all such $S$'s is also a subset of $X \times X$. So an element of $R$ is of the form $(x,y) \in X \times X$, and by the construction of $R$ we know that $(x,y) \in S$ for any $S$ which is an equivalence relation om $X$.

Now that we've untangled the definitions/notations, you should be able to see how to finish the problem.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks for the clarifications!! $$$$ Let .$(x,y)\in S$, since $S$ is an equivalence relation it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Since $S$ is reflexive we have that $xSx$ for all $x\in X$. Since it holds that $\forall S\in S_U$: $xSx$, it follows that $xRx$, since $R$ is the intersection of all $S$. Since $S$ is symmetric we have that $xSy \iff ySx$ for all $x,y\in X$. Since it holds that $\forall S\in S_U$: $xSy\iff ySx$, it follows that $xRy \iff yRx$, since $R$ is the intersection of all $S$.

Comment: Since $S$ is transitive we have that $xSy \land ySz \Rightarrow xSz$ for all $x,y,z\in X$. Since it holds that $\forall S\in S_U$: $xSy \land ySz \Rightarrow xSz$, it follows that $xRy \land yRz \Rightarrow xRz$, since $R$ is the intersection of all $S$. Is that correct? Can we just say that in that way or do we have to prove that further?

Comment: You have the right idea. But instead of starting with, "Let $(x,y) \in S$ ", start with "Let $(x,y) \in R$ " and change the argument form there. Because in general, if a pair $(x,y)$ is in some equivalence $S$, that doesn't mean it necessarily appears in every other equivalence relations.

Comment: So is the following the correct and complete proof? $$$$ 

Let $(x,y)\in R$. Then $(x,y)\in S$ for all $S\in S_U$. $ \\ $ 

Since $S$ is an equivalence relation, it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. $ \\ $ 

Since $S$ is reflexive we have that $xSx$ for all $x\in X$. Since it holds that $\forall S\in S_U: xSx$, it follows that $xRx$, since $R$ is the intersection of all $S$.

Comment: Since $S$ is symmetric we have that $xSy\iff ySx$ for all $x,in X$. Since it holds that $\forall S\in S_U: xSy\iff ySx$, it follows that $xRy\iff yRx$, since $R$ is the intersection of all $S$. 

Since $S$ is transitive we have that $xSy\land ySz\Rightarrow xSz$ for all $x,y,z\in X$. Since it holds that $\forall S\in S_U: xSy\land ySz\Rightarrow xSz$, it follows that $xRy\land yRz\Rightarrow xRz$, since $R$ is the intersection of all $S$.

Comment: I think that's fine.

Comment: Ok! Suppose that $X=\mathbb{Z}$ and $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\mid x+y\geq 100\}$, how can we define $R$ in that case?

Comment: You might want to ask a new question along the lines "What's the smallest equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ containing $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 | x + y \geq 100 \}$. Because it's a different question then the one you posed, which just shows that such a smallest equivalence relation exists.